# Advantage of CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO in opencv calibrateCamera()

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I am calibrating a camera with nominally quadratic pixels.

calibrateCamera() returns fx and fy that are very similar (~ one permil). I bootstrapped the pictures used for calibration and found that the difference between fx and fy is smaller than the bootstrap standard deviation. The best estimate is therefore that they are the same.

I would like to get the best image out in the end. My question is: Should I use the flag CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO?

Further explanation of my considerations:
My guesses are that the algorithm either runs the whole algorithm as normally and then fixes fx at the end, or runs the y direction first and uses fy as fixed fx for the x direction. The first case seems to me to give a (slightly) bad cx. In either case I would expect a better result without CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO. Or does it do something smarter? Are there any cases where CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO is advantageous?

That was three questions, but I am mostly interested in an answer to the first one.

Comment: there are a lot of parameters that are determined by optimization during calibration. Typically, the fewer parameters have to be found, the less influence will noise and measurement errors have. I dont know about the actual algorithm, but I would guess that there is a numerical optimization just uses one parameter less when fixing the aspect ratio.

Comment: @Micka: Thanks, I generally agree. However, in this case, if only fy is calibrated and later applied to x, I have the impression that the x data is left out for f calibration, and the noise is therefore actually increased. But I do not know.

Comment: you misunderstand. it uses *one* parameter for *both* in the optimization. it **does not** just copy the value over.